# Check if css class is contained in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

For this div:

```
<div class="table room"> </div>
```

Is it possible to use the `attr` parameter to check if the div contains the CSS class "room"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div.table').hasClass('room');

if($('div.table').hasClass('room')) {
  alert('Yes');
}
```

See more about **[`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)**

#### According to comment

You can also use `id` instead of `class` i.e

```
$('div#someId').hasClass('room')
```

Comment: I assume I can use the div id instead of the css class for same effect ?

Comment: @user701254 sure, you can use `id`

Answer (score 6):

Use hasclass:

```
$('div.table').hasClass('room')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.table').hasClass('room')
```

more crude approach using `attr`

```
if ($('.table').attr('room') != undefined)
```